# Unable to host WCF Service, Throwing an error as System.Threading.Tasks is not supported

Tags: wcf, wcf-data-services, wcf-binding

In VS 2013, I am setting up the WCF service. I am getting an error as 
" This operation is not supported in the WCF Test Client because it uses System.Threading.Tasks "

[image]

Comment: So, what do you want anyone to _do_ about that? Is the message not clear?

Comment: I am not able to fix it. Could you please suggest me how to fix this

Comment: Fix it? Why do you think it's broken?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the synchronous methods are working then your service is working fine. The problem you are having is the fact that the WCF test ***client*** does not support methods that return a Task, you must either use the synchronous methods with the built in client or write your own client that uses the asynchronous methods to test your service..

There is nothing you can do to "fix" it to make the WCF test client work with asynchronous methods.